# jQuery doesn't sort my options

Tags: jquery

I have an option-select HTML thing. The JS code:

```
var inviteds = $('#clientMenuEvents_edit select[name="everybody"]');
inviteds.find('option').sort (function(a,b) {
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

I debugged the function, `a.innerHTML.toLowerCase()` gives the string, but it just can't order that list, nothing happens. Everybody does it like that - but it acts like I didn't do anything.

Comment: Do you want to sort the result set or the order of the elements in the dom?

Comment: the options. I guess then you meant the "elements in the dom"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sorting the elements, but the sort affects only the element set, not the DOM. If you use `.append()` to place the set back into the select element, they'll be added in the sorted order.

```
inviteds.find('option').sort (function(a,b) {
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo( inviteds );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CAZCf/1/